# How to print JavaScript based on Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Allow me to elaborate.
I have this Ajax script which is fetching for one thing. The refresh_on. 
What does it do? It either returns 0 OR 1.

```
 function startRefresh() {
        setTimeout(startRefresh, 60000);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {task: "reload"},
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, attr){
                    if (attr.refresh_on == 0) {
                        //this doesn't work 
                        /*Write/return this in JavaScript:*/ line[1]="Offline.";
                    } else {
                        //this doesn't work
                        /*Write/return this in JavaScript:*/ line[1]="Online.";
                    };
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

If the ajax returns with refresh_on == 0 OR refresh_on == 1 - I want it to print its respective array item. It **must** be an array item.

```
</head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var line=new Array()
      startRefresh();
      //output either "line[1]=\"Offline.\""; or "line[1]=\"Online.\"";
    </script>
  </body>
```

This is the PHP file:

```
if (isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == "reload") {
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT refresh_on FROM refresh");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $encode = Array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $encode[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($encode);  
}
```

If it matters - this is the JSON response:

```
[{"refresh_on":1}]
```

Is there a way to insert/output/print the array item using the function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the response

Comment: What does the 1 in line[1] suposed to mean? are you making a loging system where each refresh will say Online or Offline?

Comment: can't do  much without seeing all the pieces of the puzzle. All you have is a string showing in `$.each`...where's it supposed to go? It's not even assigned to a variable. What does data look like also. Mention an array...but no idea what array you are talking about to output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a couple things that might be going on here, but to begin, you're wrapping your variable in a quote, so all that is happening is a string is being made and immediately being dropped to the floor. Let's start off by doing something like the following:

```
 function startRefresh() {
        setTimeout(startRefresh, 60000);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {task: "reload"},
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, attr){
                    if (attr.refresh_on == 0) {
                        //this doesn't work 
                        line[1] = "Offline.";
                    } else {
                        //this doesn't work
                        line[1]= "Online.";
                    };
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, if I recall correctly, the ajax function is going to be calling your success callback, which is going to take over your local scope. I don't believe `line` is going to be accessible to that callback, so we should/could actually move that callback to its own function within a closure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

  var line = []; 
  startRefresh();

  function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh, 60000);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'refresh.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: { task: "reload" },
      success: refreshResponse
    }); 
  }

  function refreshResponse(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, attr) {
      if (attr.refresh_on == 0) {
        line[1] = "Offline.";
      } else {
        line[1] = "Online.";
      }   
    }); 
  }

})();

</script>
```

We've wrapped that in a self executing function to give us some nice encapsulation to work with, and because `line` is in a function which refreshResponse is found, that variable should be accessible to it.

But we're not done yet!

For one, we could easily make that variable assignment a little easier, like so:

```
line[1] = (attr.refresh_on == 0) ? "Offline." : "Online.";
```

...and we're also going to want to triple up on that equality statement, just to avoid variable coercion:

```
line[1] = (attr.refresh_on === 0) ? "Offline." : "Online.";
```

Give that a shot and let's see where we're at.

Comment: I tried this. It is currently not putting it inside of the script at all. What I need is: After the function is called - based on what the json is - the script will return either :line[1] = "Offline."; or line[1] = "Online.";

Comment: It's kind of like writing/adding more JavaScript into the script in which the startRefresh() is being called - using JavaScript.

Comment: It really depends on *where* you are using that `line` variable, in addition to how you're using it. Perhaps you could include more context in a JSFiddle?

Comment: You are still recursively calling setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting `"line[1]=\"Offline.\"";` to do, but it's not going to do anything. Perhaps you mean: `line[1]= "Offline";`? Try putting this line of code there instead to test that it's working: `console.log('Offline');`

If the line is getting executed and you see the output in your console, you would just have to target some HTML element that you want to put the "Offline" string into, for instance:

```
<div id="status"></div>
<script>
....
var status = document.getElementById("status");
if (attr.refresh_on == 0) {
   status.textContent = "Offline";
} else {
    status.textContent = "Online";
};
....
</script>
```